# Rails 2.3.14 setting expire_after for sessions is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, nginx, passenger

I have next config in my environment.rb:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :cookie_store
config.action_controller.session = {
:expire_after   => 14.days,
:domain         => DOMAIN,
:session_key    => '_session',
:secret         => 'some_string'
}
```

Setting session_store to **active_record_store** or **mem_cache_store** didn't help.
Also i've tried just setting cookie from controller (with all founded options for expire):

```
cookies[:test] = { :value => 'test' , :expires => 3600.to_i.from_now.utc }
```

In both ways all sessions and cookies are deleted after closing browser window - they are only for browser session.
I've tried almost all variants founded in the Internet - no luck(

My config is: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, rails 2.3.14, ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7, Phusion Passenger version 3.0.11 and Nginx compiled by Phusion Passenger.

I've an options that it's Nginx not allowing setting some headers but also didn't find any solution.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

UPD.
i've tried to put all configs for sessions to config/initializers/session_store.rb - nothing changed. 
i have a feeling that it's not a rails problem. may it be phusion + nginx error?
i don't even know how to check where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :expire_after   => 14.days,
  :domain         => DOMAIN,
  :session_key    => '_session',
  :secret         => 'some_string'
}
```

Comment: i've tried this variant also. no luck - expire after closing browser window

Comment: HI @sailor i used this in my rails3 code but after session expiry it will gives nil error for user_id, is their any way to redirect user to login page on refresh

Comment: For me this works in rails 2.3.18. It is probably obvious, but you have to restart the server after changing something in an initializer. Also in chrome you can easily check the `expires/max-age` of a cookie (in the resources tab).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :cookie_store
ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 14.days
```

For Rails 3

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => "whatever", :expire_after => 14.days
```

Comment: i've checked the cookies section in my browser and when i click on cookie "_session" it shows that it will expire after the end of browser session. And it's true - i'm closing browser and open again and no cookie )